# How to find out if a solution is deployad with -FullTrustBinDeployment parameter

Tags: powershell, solution-package, solution-deployment, farm-solution

I am trying to find a piece of PowerShell script that gives me the list of solutions deployed with FullTrustBinDeployment parameter.